# Arduino serial port COM1 problem

Tags: 14.04, java, serial-port, arduino

I bought an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and installed Arduino IDE 1.6.5. But when I want to upload a sketch to the Arduino board I get this error:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "COM1": No such file or directory 
>   ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) LTS.

```
    hakan@hakan-pc:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
ls: /dev/ttyUSB0'e erişilemedi: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok(In English: No such a file like this)

 hakan@hakan-pc:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Tem  8 22:40 /dev/ttyS0
```

While the Arduino is plugged into the computer, `dmesg | tail` shows:

```
    hakan@hakan-pc:~$ dmesg | tail
[   21.784795] sound hdaudioC1D3: hda-codec: out of range cmd 3:5:707:ffffffff
[   21.784969] sound hdaudioC1D3: hda-codec: out of range cmd 3:5:707:ffffffbf
[   21.786110] sound hdaudioC1D0: hda-codec: out of range cmd 0:5:707:ffffffff
[   21.792705] sound hdaudioC1D0: hda-codec: out of range cmd 0:5:707:ffffffff
[   26.849759] sound hdaudioC1D0: hda-codec: out of range cmd 0:5:707:ffffffbf
[   27.515096] init: Failed to spawn nvidia-persistenced main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   43.647261] audit: type=1400 audit(1436384452.263:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2246 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   43.647270] audit: type=1400 audit(1436384452.263:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2246 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   43.647654] audit: type=1400 audit(1436384452.267:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2246 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   87.513268] systemd-hostnamed[2572]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `dmesg` code does not contain the information about plugging the arduino board... please change it with the relevant one. By the way, prepending `LANG=C` to a command should give you error messages in English.

Comment: How are you getting **COM1** on Linux. That's how Windows names

Comment: prakharsingh95 yes i know but i don't understand why seen as COM1.Anyway in /dev directory there's nothing like COMx or ttyACMx. There are only tty(x) and ttyS(x).

Answer (score 21):

1. Connect your Arduino hardware.Open Arduino IDE.
2. Go to "Tool".
3. Go to "Port".
4. Select the port to which Arduino is connected.(If no other external drive is connected except Arduino,there will be only one port)

   This will tell Arduino IDE the port to which your hardware is connected.
   After that,you will be able to upload your sketch successfully

Comment: It's (port menu) greyed out..

Comment: @hakan try running arduino as root . in terminal write "sudo arduino"

Comment: @kasnish i tried but it's not worked

Comment: what a simple & perfect solution!!!!  Save my day. I tried out many other commands in terminal that makes no change in my progress. Thanks alot.

Comment: @ShankiBansal your welcome!

Answer (score 9):

If you run Arduino IDE on Ubuntu (Arduino 1.5.7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in my case), most possibly you cannot upload to Arduino board, caused by the error of:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

To fix it, enter the command:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Where  is your user name in Ubuntu, /dev/ttyUSB0 is the detected device of your Arduino board.

First line doing add group (dialout) to username 
Second line doing write and read permission to "/dev/ttyUSB0"

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error on Ubuntu 14.04 with Arduino Uno.
What worked for me was first selecting the appropriate port under Tools > Port and then changing the permission of the port using command like:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then the error disappeared and I could upload fine.

Comment: I had this error `Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/ttyACM0; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Permission denied.`  So had to use your `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 ` magic, but it DID NOT HELP. So I had to use use this command `sudo adduser <username> dialout` and then logout/login to make things work

Answer (score 1):

I received the same message in Ubuntu 14.04 and the 1.0.5 version of the IDE.

Loading the [FTDI chip D2XX](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) drivers resolved the issue (I just downloaded and followed the README install). The serial port was available, and I was also able to successfully upload to the Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

Change in the *lib/preferences.txt* file:

The string from

> serial.port=COM1

to

> serial.port=/dev/ttyUSB0

Answer (score 0):

1. Permissions on the USB port

   As a Linux user you'll need to be a member of the group *dialout* to be able to read and write to any `/dev/tty*` connections.

   Thus, making the connection world-writable *or* running the Arduino IDE as root is both **not** the way to go.

   It will be enough to add your user to the group *dialout* and re-login afterwards:

   ```
   sudo adduser *username* dialout
   ```
2. USB connection *COM1*

   The Arduino IDE is written in Java, but it is probably still OS dependent. Is it likely that you did use the Windows ZIP package of the IDE on a Linux system?
3. USB connection general

   Obviously your computer did not recognize the USB connection to the Arduino. Try to avoid USB hubs or USB sockets that some displays provide, and instead use a direct connection.

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu 18.04, the package 'arduino' gives a similar problem.

My workaround has been to get the one from the Arduino web site. Just extract it and make ./arduino to launch it. It works fine.